# Calculate an approximation of $\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\log(xy)xy}{-1+\log(xy)}dxdy$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

*Motivation.* I was thinking in the more simple case of (6), I am saying the case $r=s=1$, that tell us this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AperysConstant.html). Then in this case one can check that the identity holds using integration methods. When I did it I've considered from Hata's integral the following different integral in this

> **Question.** What's about $$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\log(xy)xy}{-1+\log(xy)}dxdy?$$

*Remark.* The context was that I was trying with my imagination different expressions for an hypothetical similar (6) but now for $\sum_{k=r+1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^3}$, where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function. For example I tried also consider $\int_0^1\left(\int_1^\infty\left(\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{xy(1-(1-xy)z)}\right)dy\right)dz$, but I understand that it is science fiction to find an expression for $\sum_{k=r+1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^3}$ from this random method.

*My attempt.* I can deduce the following statement  $$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\log(xy)xy}{-1+\log(xy)}dxdy=\frac{1}{4}+\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{dxdy}{-1+\log(xy)},$$ and I know that $$\int\frac{dx}{-1+\log(xy)}=e\frac{\operatorname{Ei}(\log(xy)-1)}{y}+\operatorname{ constant}.$$
Then can we finish the example to get the integral in the Question in terms of particular values of special functions? **Thanks in advance.**

### References:

Hata, *A New Irrationality Measure for* $\zeta(3)$, Acta Arith. 92, 47-57 (2000).

Comment: What exactly is (6)? politeness would dictate that you don't make potential repliers go hunt down what exactly you are referring to.

Comment: @nbubis many thanks for your attention. If you do the calculations for $r=s=1$ of (6) you can deduce a similar integral that I've written. Many thanks.

Comment: Again, you haven't said what $(6)$ is.

Comment: I'm sorry then, but it is (6) of the MathWorld article. Then is the identity (6) case $r=s=1$. Many thanks @nbubis

Comment: All users $$\int_0^1\left(\int_1^\infty\left(\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{xy(1-(1-xy)z)}\right)dy\right)dz$$ corresponds to my *attempt* to relate the case $r=s=1$ with the specialization $r=1$ of this tail $\sum_{k=r+1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^3}$. As I said I understand that it isn't a reasoning mathematical, but I am interestng in to know an integral representation for this $\sum_{k=r+1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^3}$, if such similar representation is feasible. If you know some idea to exploit  it and you want to edit a new question in this site Mathematics Stack Exchange it is the best. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change variables $xy/e=t$ to get
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{dxdy}{-1+\log(xy)}=\int_0^1 dy \frac{e}{y}\int_0^{y/e}\frac{dt}{\log t}=\int_0^1 dy \frac{e}{y}\mathrm{li}(y/e)\ ,
$$
where $\mathrm{li}(z)$ is the logarithmic integral. The second integral admits an antiderivative
$$
\int dy \frac{1}{y}\mathrm{li}(y/e)=\text{li}\left(\frac{y}{e}\right) \ln \left(\frac{y}{e}\right)-\frac{y}{e}+C\ ,
$$
therefore your double integral reads
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{dxdy}{-1+\log(xy)}=-1-e \text{li}\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)\ .
$$

Comment: Many thanks for your early answer, and attention. Now I am studying the answer.

Comment: Many thanks one more time for your trick to get the integratio and refer the antiderivative.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{xy}xy \over -1 + \ln\pars{xy}}\,\dd x\,\dd y =
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{xy}xy
\bracks{-\int_{0}^{\infty}\pars{xy \over \expo{}}^{t}\,\dd t}\,\dd x\,\dd y
\\[5mm] = &\
-\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-t}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{xy}x^{t + 1}
y^{t + 1}\,\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
-2\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-t}
\bracks{\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x}x^{t + 1}
\,\dd x}\pars{\int_{0}^{1}y^{t + 1}\,\dd y}\,\dd t =
2\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-t} \over \pars{t + 2}^{3}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
2\expo{}^2\int_{2}^{\infty}{\expo{-t} \over t^{3}}\,\dd t =
2\expo{}^{2}\bracks{\mrm{E}_{3}\pars{2} \over 2^{3 - 1}} =
\bbx{\ds{{1 \over 2}\,e^{2}\,\mrm{E}_{3}\pars{2}}} \approx 0.1113
\end{align}

> $\ds{\mrm{E}_{p}\pars{z}}$ is the
>   [Generalized Exponenential Integral Function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.19.E2).

Comment: Many thanks, you are very generous with this. I am going to study your nice answer.

Comment: @user243301 Thanks. It's nice it was helpful for you.

Comment: I understand the first identity $\int a^tdt=a^t/log(a)+\text{constant}$, and next calculations in second line, but I don't know where is the  $\log(y)$ in the third line. Many thanks.

Comment: $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\ln(x)x^{t + 1}y^{t + 1}\,dx\,dy + \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\ln(y)x^{t + 1}y^{t + 1}\,dx\,dy$. If you exchange $x$ by $y$( and $y$ by $x$ ) in the second integral you get the first one. So, you have twice the first integral. Note the factor $2$ which multiplies the whole double integration.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, very thanks much for these calculations, sincerely are nice.